# Checking recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there a way to check my recurrence relation, so I can confirm I did it correctly?

$a_k = -4a_{k-1} -4a_{k-2}$ with $a_0 = 0$   $a_1= -1$

My answer: $a_n = 0(-2)^n - ½n(-2)^n$

Comment: Could your format your math so that it is a little more obvious what you came up with?

Comment: I think your formula gives $a_1=1$; I believe you want $a_n=\frac{n}{2}(-2)^n$

Comment: How did you determine $a_1$ was 1 and not -1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to check your result. Calculate $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\dots$ using the recurrence relation $a_k=-4a_{k-1}-4a_{k-2}$, and also calculate them using your formula $a_n=-\frac12(-2)^n$, and see if you get the same numbers.

Comment: Do I drop the $n$ from $-1/2n$